# What do you call a bugfix which, you know very well, doesn't fix the root cause?

Tags: terminology

In medical terms, this is called a "**symptomatic treatment**". What is it called in the context of software development?

Answer (score 7):

**Hack** (or possibly **dirty hack**)

Comment: I would say "Hack" is used when talking to other programmers and "Workaround" is what is used when explaining what you did to customers/management.

Answer (score 7):

"Workaround" is the term I would suggest.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a [***kludge***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge).

Answer (score 2):

"Patch" or "temporary fix".

Comment: I disagree with this. Your answer addresses the circumstances or temporal constraints of the fix, not its nature.

Comment: Bug fixes are often called "patches", especially in games or when dealing with security issues. "Patch" can definitely refer to a good, lasting fix.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to call them "band-aids".  Feel free to replace with your region's most-known brand of adhesive bandages, if you like.  :)